# Mapper parsing exception when field is populated

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch in order to store all the logging from my REST API with Winston. After testing it around and making some requests through my API, I notice that I get `'object mapping for [fields.meta.res.body.x] tried to parse field [x] as object, but found a concrete value'` multiple times. That happens because I don't always populate the fields, that can result in either a field with an ID or a field with an object with the populated data.

e.g. The response can either be:

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642"
}
```

or

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": {
        "_id": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642",
        "name": "admin"
    }
}
```

Is there any way that I can make a field accept two different types of values? If not, what's the best way to work around that issue? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have an `object` field (i.e. `role`) contains a concrete value (i.e. a string) and vice versa. You need to decide on one or the other. In your case, what would seem reasonable is to always specify `role` as an object and leave `role.name` to null if there's no value. If instead of this:

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642"          <-- this is no good since role is an object
}
```

use this:

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": {
        "_id": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642",      <-- specify the id here
        "name": null                            <-- use null here
    }
}
```

And if you suffer from the opposite problem (i.e. trying to fit an object into a string), then you need to make sure that `role` actually contains the value of `role._id`, i.e. instead of this

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": {
        "_id": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642",
        "name": null                      
    }
}
```

use this:

```
{
    "_id": "5c6be1ab42cb9db50832469e",
    "name": "xyz",
    "role": "5c3e003efb6fc0600be0d642"          <-- this should be role._id
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @Val. That sure seems like the best approach to it. At what level should I do that transformation since I cannot do it with the help of mongoose?

Comment: Using an [ingest processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ingest.html) would certainly help, but I'm not sure if mongoose allows to specify a pipeline.